# Why use Automappers ValueResolver?

Tags: automapper

Why do this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyObject, AnotherObject>().
ForMember(x => x.DateAsString, m => m.ResolveUsing<StringToDateTimeFormatter>());

private class StringToDateTimeFormatter : ValueResolver<DateTime, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(DateTimesource)
    {
        return source.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

 }
```

when you can do this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyObject, AnotherObject>().
ForMember(x => x.DateAsString, m => m.MapFrom(x => x.Date.ToString("yyy-MM-dd")));
```

???

**Update**

Here's an example on how to do more complex business logic

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyObject, AnotherObject>().
ForMember(x => x.DateAsString, m => m.MapFrom(n => MyMethod(n.DateAsString)));

    private object MyMethod(string dateTime)
    {
        if(!MyDomainObjectIsValid(dateTime))
        {
            throw new MyValidationException();
        }

        // do more stuff
    }
```

I still don't see the need for a ValueResolver...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously for your example it is more reasonable to use just `MapFrom`. 
ValueResolvers are needed for more complicated cases. For example when you need to do some validation and throw exception accordingly.

**EDIT**
ValueResolvers provide access to the destination type and value. Here is small example.

```
public class FakeResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        if (source.Context.DestinationType == typeof(string) && source.Context.DestinationValue == "test")
            throw new Exception();
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I use a value resolver to do a lot of business object work when the mapping is more complex - the simpler lambda syntax is not that useful in this case (calling multiple static methods etc)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sure you're right but I'm not yet satisfied. See the example I added in the original question. I can perform business operations and throw exceptions without using a ValueResolver. Is possible for you to show an example where I must use a ValueResolver?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.